# Reading an XML document using pugiXml

Tags: c++, qt, pugixml

i have a problem with parsing an xml document using pugiXml, it seems to me that everything is correct but this code doesn't work :(

```
void MainWindow::open()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open");
    xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file(fileName.toStdString().c_str());

    for (pugi::xml_node node : doc.child("Person"))
    {
        qDebug(node.child_value("nom"));
        qDebug(node.child_value("Age"));
    }
}
```

Xml file format :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Persons>
<Person>
    <nom>Med</nom>
    <Age>12</Age>
</Person>
<Person>
    <nom>Nasr</nom>
    <Age>14</Age>
</Person>
<Person>
    <nom>Souad</nom>
    <Age>52</Age>
</Person>
</Persons>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "code doesn't work"? And as you are using Qt, why don't you use Qt's XML features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause is that you should use doc.child("Persons").

Document object in your case has one child Persons, that has several Person children. doc.child("Person") fails to find the node and returns a null handle.

Having said that, don't forget to check load_file return value as well.